# Automatically log in to Windows and then lock straight away

Tags: windows, windows-7, login

I am looking for a program that automatically logs into Windows when I turn the computer on, and then locks it straight away.

ie: I turn my computer on > I am automatically logged in if there is inactivity for a few seconds > The computer is then locked (ie. Win + L).

Requirements:

- free
- only logs in if there is inactivity for a user-defined time (less than 3 or so minutes)
- *locks* the computer, Windows style, not *its own style*
- runs on Windows 7 64 bit

---

I'm sure every single person reading this has had at least one time where they turn their computer on, and go away for a few minutes (maybe the toilet? :) and you returned to see you didn't login! You then had to login and wait for a few minutes to make sure all the startup programs open and, ***finally (!)*** you could start doing whatever you wanted to!

This program will help be *avoid* what I said above. It will ensure that the programs that should open on login, start opening *as soon as* the computer turns on (rather than waiting for me to come back, enter my password, and wait 5 minutes for them to start).

Comment: What does "inactivity" mean? Mouse, keyboard, joystick, MIDI, attach a USB stick, ...?

Comment: @ThomasWeller basically when the computer is completely idle. no mouse movement, keyboard keys, peripherals being used

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/352616/35237

Comment: @Tobias - that seems perfect! I'd be happy to mark that as an answer if you posted one! :)

Answer (score 6):

Do both the following:

1. [set up your account to auto-login](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx): (below is quoted from that link)

   > 1. Click Start, type `netplwiz`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   > 2. In the User Accounts dialog box, click the account you want to automatically log on to.If it is available, clear the "Users Must
   >      Enter A User Name And Password To Use This Computer" check box.
   > 3. Click OK.
   > 4. In the Automatically Log On dialog box, enter the user’s password twice and click OK.

   This will start the Advanced User Accounts Access Panel, and allow you to switch on Windows' built-in auto-login function for that account. This is a built-in windows function, there isn't a time-out option to only initiate the login after a period of inactivity.
2. With your favorite text editor, create a `.cmd` batch file (not `.bat`).  The file name does not matter, I called mine `autolock.cmd`. The file should contain the following commands:

   ```
   timeout /t 10
   rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
   ```
3. Move or copy it into your "All Users" startup folder.  On Windows 8/10 you can easily navigate to the All Users startup folder in File Explorer by typing `shell:common startup` in the path field (the current user's startup folder is `shell:startup`).

Step 1 above logs you in automatically after every restart. The `.cmd` file then gets run a few seconds after login; it will wait for ten seconds, and then lock the workstation. If you don't want the lock to kick in, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt

Comment: Is there a Windows 10 alternative for this?

Comment: Updated to remove the dependency on 3rd party software.  This can all be accomplished easily using native Windows commands.

Comment: Very slick, helped me launch VMWare Workstation and VM, then lock computer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Free, open-source, Windows), something along the lines of:

```
Sleep, 60000  ; 60 seconds (change this depending on how long you want to wait)
Send #l       ; hold down the Windows key and then press the letter "l" -> lock Windows
```

[compile the script into an EXE with ahk2exe](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) and add it in startup.

Comment: Cool, but will this work *before* I login?? Or will I need to login and then this will work? Adding it to startup would mean after 60 seconds of being logged in, the computer will be locked

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://ahkscript.org/). Apparently the AutoHotKey version you link to is out of date. Maybe that is why your answer on my minimizing question is not working?

Comment: @ṧнʊß Yes it wouldn't get locked directly, but should be pretty quick if you get rid of the sleep. Thanks the link, I updated but still same issue :/

Comment: I meant I want to login automatically after a few minutes, and then lock immediately...

Comment: Oh sorry, now I get it :) I'll leave the answer as it can be use as an alternative second step to energy number's answer, but yeah first step turn on auto login!

Comment: Yeah, both your answers are great! But it's the auto login step that I need now...! I'm going to try to run a script that runs as a service on boot, but I don't know where to start...

Comment: (Test102038273948263937)

Comment: what?? does?? that?? mean??

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to reproduce a bug in the Android application :-)